# AF not working on Manual mode AV or TV mode, and shutter not opening. however both AF and shutter opening on auto and not flash -EOS400d

Tags: canon, dslr, autofocus, troubleshooting, canon-400d

I am testing an old EOS 400d to see if its worth using-

on auto mode and no flash mode- the camera focuses, I get the green light then it takes the photo once I fully press the trigger button,

in all manual modes including full manual AF, TV and P, the autofocuses tries to focus on an object but didn't, with no green light and audible fussiness. then when I fully press down the trigger the shutter doesn't open and no photo is taken. I've tried this all the AF options. servo AI and one shot

in manual focus mode the shutter opens and the camera takes photos in all modes,

any advice?

Comment: What is `full manual AF`? It's either autofocus or manual focus? Also, what is the lens, and did you try with another one?

Comment: What are the lighting conditions where you are doing your tests? Bright daylight outdoors? Indoors at night? Etc.?